# Command line tool to convert date format

Tags: shell, datetime, command-line, string-formatting

I have a text file (Markdown, actually, but close enough) with dates in a slightly annoying US format `%m/%d/%Y`.  I'd like it to be in ISO-8601 format everywhere throughout.

I could easily write a 5-10 line script to do this specific conversion, but it feels like the sort of thing someone has written a more complete version of already. I just don't know what this hypothetical tool is called.

My imagined tool would take arbitrary formats for input and output (but from the world of datetime formats), although maybe with shortcuts for common ones.  Basically, a datetime-aware `sed` is what I would want.  So I might run, e.g.:

```
$ datecvt -i US -o ISO8601 < myfile.txt > gooddates.txt
$ # ... or ...
$ datecvt -i '%m/%d/%Y' -o '%Y-%m-%d' --inplace myfile.txt
```

Perhaps slightly different usage syntax, but that sort of thing.  Does it exist? (for OSX, but almost all Linux-oriented tools can be compiled, and have been with Homebrew).

Comment: have you looked at `date` ?  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears GNU date interprets `01/02/2018` as January 2nd

```
$ date -d '01/02/2018'
Tue Jan  2 00:00:00 EST 2018
```

So you can do this:

```
$ date -d '01/02/2018' -I
2018-01-02
```

Or, if you want to be explicit about the input format, perl is useful:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -slE 'say Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%m/%d/%Y")->ymd' -- -date=01/02/2018
2018-01-02
```

Comment: I don't understand your meaning, @DavidC.Rankin.

Comment: @DavidMertz it was regarding the little snowflake awards that let you overlay a hat, or glasses, or just whatever the award related to over your normal icon. Looks like that ended at the end of 2018 -- RIP.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` utility does a part of what I want.  But only for one single string, not to process a file or stream.

I know how to do the task in various programming languages. What I hoped for was a command-line utility to do it. I decided to try to write a "moderately good" version in Julia. Not because it's necessarily the best language to choose (startup time is terrible), but simply because I wanted to play with the language. I'm sure this early attempt is not idiomatic or optimal, but it does basically the goal:

[gist.github.com/DavidMertz/447661d67f7b3f5ffa3c23d56f3b7294](https://gist.github.com/DavidMertz/447661d67f7b3f5ffa3c23d56f3b7294)

Comment: What's your OS?